# How to add onclick event to GeoServer layer?

Tags: javascript, dictionary, openlayers, geoserver

I have a city guide map project that uses openlayers library and also uses GeoServer for layers. The project have layers list and get the layers from GeoServer via a java page. One of the layers have description property. I want to add onclick event to that layer. When users click a point of that layer, description must be showed with pop-up. But I don't know how to do. Should I do it GeoServer side? Should I use openlayers for this?

Comment: duplicate of https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133235/openlayers-3-wms-getfeatureinfo-popup (amongst others)

Comment: Thank you, but my project's openlayer version is 2. As far as I know updating version 2 to 3 is complicated. The project is very big and I'm newbie on openlayers and GeoServer. Is there other way to do what I want?

Comment: principal is the same though - see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24187/how-to-do-getfeatureinfo-in-openlayers2

Comment: Thank you @IanTurton. I'll try to apply this example.